# How do I specify the default font sizer in CK Editor v3

Tags: default, ckeditor, font-size

How do I specify the default font size for CKEditor.  I tried changing contents.css (body -> font-size) and I tried changing config.js (config.fontSize_defaultLabel) without any success.  Does anyone know where i should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track with the contents.css file.

Is your problem that the font size while working in the editor is not correct or is it that the font size isn't being carried over to the page where you actually display the content?

As you know, ckeditor/contents.css is the default style sheet that is loaded while working in the editor, but if you use "config.contentsCss" to call another style sheet, contents.css won't be loaded.

You can call multiple style sheets like this:

```
config.contentsCss = ['/contents.css', '/css/anotherstylesheet.css'];
```

---

If the font size isn't being carried over to the actual page display, you'll need to set the font size in the style sheet used for the actual pages, the default font size used in the editor isn't inserted into the content output by the editor.

"config.fontSize_defaultLabel" is a label only, it doesn't have any effect on the content. Normally, when you load the editor, the font size selector will display "Size". If you set "fontSize_defaultLabel", the font size selector will display whatever value you entered.

If you can provide more details about the problem, I'll try to post a more accurate answer.

Be Well,
Joe